# Styles are missed in my bootstrap modal

Tags: jquery, css, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

Using ajax get request I am calling html and making it modal .but some styles are missed in modal what is reason for missing styles.[image]

To is multi select text with auto complete in bootstrap

used  jquery to getting modal

```
$(function () {
  $('#sendmsg').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $.get('/Message/sendform', function (data) {

        $(document.body).append(data);
        $('#form_modal10').modal();
    });
 });
});
```

with out ajax calling ,View in asp.net mvc working like this.

how to get like this using jquery ajax.
[image]

Comment: have you included the file in the modal page???...if not, you need to!

Comment: I have included all files in layout page(mvc)

Comment: This looks pretty styled for me. Perhaps with your html and css and a working example, i could help more about what's overwriting bootstrap's styling.

Comment: you will need to include all the files `js` and `css` in this modal window page....and as Milche said, working fiddle would be more helpful!!

Comment: I also have edit icons like b,I,U, colors etc..those are also missed

Comment: mate...you have to understand that modal windows take the path of the source files from themselves not from the path they are called.....my suggestion would be to give absolute path in your modal window page.

Comment: Are you using any plugin to make that dropdown? If yes then initialize the dropdown in ajax success method, to get the respective classes for styling.

Comment: Your style is made by an jquery plugin (looks like chosen) ? If yes, you have to init it when ajax call is ended.